# get data from div in ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, opencart

Im not very familiar with `ajax` and `javascript`, but i need some help so i will try to explain as clearly as i can!

I have the following button with this javascript:

```
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/leasing_plans/confirm',
    cache: false,
data:{
  egn:$('#input-payment-egn').val(),
  months: $('input[name=months]:checked').val()
},
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },
    success: function() {
        location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }
});
```

I have the following radio buttons :

```
   <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi3"  />3 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni3"  />3 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi6"  />6 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni6"  />6 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi9"  />9 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni9"  />9 месеца x </label>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
```

I have also the following divs with the same id`s like radio button values:

```
 <div id="tbi3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 3  30.36% <br>
    <p>Прочетох</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 3  30.36% <br>
    <p>Правилата</p>
</div> 

<div id="tbi6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 6 34.49% <br>
    <p>Прочетох и</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly /> Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 6 x 34.49%  <br>
    <p>Правилата за ползване</p>
</div>
```

BUT the problem is that im getting only the value of the selected `radio button`, i want to get the information in the `div` that is with the same `id` as the `radio button` name selected.
Thanks everybody, i will update my question if im not understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made 2 changes.  The data that you are sending for months only gets the value of the checkbox, which is the id of the div holding the data.  So I made a variable to hold that id, and then in the data section used jquery to get the div with that id, and then grab the text of the input inside the div.

```
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
  //add this line:
  var cbval = $('input[name=months]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/leasing_plans/confirm',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      egn: $('#input-payment-egn').val(),
      //change this line to:
      months: $('#' + cbval).text()
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },
    success: function() {
      location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }
});
```

Comment: whoops, I guess the text isn't in the input field.  Try now.

Comment: nnnope... i dont get any data

Comment: Add alert($('#' + cbval).text()); as the 3rd line and tell me what it says.

Comment: the alert contains exactly the div that i wanted to get!

Comment: OK now I'm confused.  From the code you posted, I assumed you wanted to send the text in the div to a web service at: index.php?route=payment/leasing_plans/confirm.  Are you saying all you wanted was the text inside the div?

Comment: Yes, but im not getting the text..i dont know why! There are 2 forms im dont get anything from both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153289/discussion-between-lancew-and--).

Comment: Exactly what i needed! The mistake was on php side! Just this `type: 'get',` must be `type: 'post',` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple enough solution would be to keep the selected radio's value in a variable before posting (before the `$.ajax` command):

```
var selectedReadio = $('input[name=months]:checked').val();
```

And then you can use that value to get the div with the same ID's text:

```
var divCorresponding = $('#' + selectedReadio).text();
```

In your question you mentioned getting the corresponding DIV's *"information"*, which is for  my understanding, its text, so I used `.text()` in the example above, but you can get any of its properties this way.

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев Great. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: okay the first line i must put before the `$.ajax` command, but the second one?

Comment: And how i must use this variables here: `data:{
      egn:$('#input-payment-egn').val(),
      months: $('input[name=months]:checked').val()
    },`

Comment: Can you help me?